# How to set default.aspx as default start point for visual studio debugger?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, settings, default

In a solution with many projects and pages, if you are working on file different than default.aspx and start debugging, VS will try to start the execution from the file you are working on, in many cases you will get error messages.

is there any way to set a page like "default.aspx" as starting point without having to open it and switch to it?

Comment: from the project explorer right click on the page and select set as startup page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click on the file in solution explorer & click on set as start page.

[image]

Comment: is it the same as setting the `<defaultDocument>` in Web.config?

Answer (score 2):

if you have multiple projects in your Visual Studio solution, right click on the web application project as select set as startup project, then on the `default.aspx` page you want to be used as entry page of your debugging right click and select set as start page in the context menu. All of this in Visual Studio solution explorer, works fine with me since the times of Visual Studio.NET 2003 :)

Comment: the combination of the two answers listed solved the problems! I can set only one as answer.